# RSpec Matchers Not Working (Expect Not Supported)

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have researched this and every thing I've read says that the following should work:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/expectations'
include RSpec::Matchers

RSpec.describe 'Posts' do
  it 'should return 200 response when getting posts' do
    result_posts = RestClient.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    expect(result_posts.code).to eq(200)
  end
end
```

I have that in file (`json_spec.rb`) in my `spec` directory. This is using RSpec 3.5.4.

The message being received when running this spec is:

```
only the `receive`, `have_received` and `receive_messages` matchers
are supported with `expect(...).to`, but you have provided: 
#<RSpec::Matchers::BuiltIn::Eq:0x007f9b43590f48>
```

One post suggested that I should be using

```
extend RSpec::Matchers
```

rather than trying to "include" them. I did that and the exact same error appears.

Yet another post suggested I should no longer be requiring "rspec/expectations" but rather just "rspec". That doesn't work either. (Yet another post said the exact opposite, of course. But at least I covered my bases there.)

Another post suggested that the include (or maybe the extend or maybe even both) had to go in an RSpec configure block, as such:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  include RSpec::Matchers
end
```

That, however, also does not work.

What you see above is literally all that I have in my `spec` directory. My `spec_helper.rb` file initially just contained the require statements and the include directive. I moved them to the actual spec file (as shown above) just to see if that was the issue.

I'm not using Rails or Cucumber so, to my knowledge, there is no wider context in which I can, or should, be including the matchers.

I have to assume I'm missing something fairly fundamental here but none of the RSpec documentation has been much of a roadmap about this particular issue.

Comment: RSpec works for me without lines 2 and 3. What do you get when you remove `require 'rspec/expectations'` and `include RSpec::Matchers`? I suspect that is the cause of your problems.

Comment: @MarkoAvlijaš Ah, wait. Interesting. So if I remove BOTH -- I originally misread and only removed one -- then it seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MarkoAvlijaš (see comment to post), the issue was apparently having the explicit require as well as the include statement at all.

Once those were removed, the spec file executed without issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove this line from spec_helper.rb: `config.expect_with(:rspec) { |c| c.syntax = :should }`